# How to remove "site email address on behalf of" and just keep the sender email address in "from:" part of a mail from drupal 7

Tags: emails

I am getting from part of a mail sent from my drupal 7 website like below

From: (site mail address) **On Behalf Of** (sender mail address)

Here I want to remove everything except sender email address, how can I do this?

I have found following url but it is expired

http://www.fosspedia.com/drupal-remove-on-behalf-of-from-the-sent-mails/

Any help???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can write a simple module, and in your module insert this function. [Here](https://drupal.org/node/461324) is where i got the idea

```
function yourmodule_mail_alter(&$message)
{
    $message['headers']['Sender'] = $message['headers']['From'];
}
```

If you want to go with quick sketch comment, in the link to completely get rid of the headers use

```
<?php
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
  unset($message['headers']['Sender']);
  unset($message['headers']['Errors-To']);
  unset($message['headers']['Return-Path']);
}
?>
```

There is also a module that can help out with this [mail headers](https://drupal.org/project/mail_headers)

> Control and modify any (almost any) mail header. Mail Headers allows
>   you to:

Comment: have you tried it out anytime?

Comment: Yes, and it worked fine.

Comment: In the above three solutions which one do you suggest me to use with respect to my scenario?

Comment: They are now just two. I would suggest using the last one.

Comment: With the last solution should I get the sender's email address in the from part? Sorry for asking without trying but my site in live. I will make changes once I get the clear picture.

Comment: Where did you see getting senders email address in there? All that was done was to unset some header variables